# How to union two python dictionaries to such two pair lists?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

for example,I have two dictionaries as below.

```
>>> x = {'a':1, 'b': 2}

>>> y = {'b':10, 'c': 11}
```

after some operation, Could I have such two lists? Thank you in advance.

```
x=['a','b','c']

y=[1,2,0] 

z=[0,10,11]
```

That means 'c' in x list does not occur in y list, so there is zero in the corresponding place of y list.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show your code and explain what is currently not working in your implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a set of the unified keys of the dictionaries, by converting their keys to sets and using the `|` sets [union operator](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set.union).

Then use the `.get` method of the dictionaries ([see here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)) to select only the keys that are contained within them (or `0` if not contained):

```
>>> x = {'a':1, 'b': 2}
>>> y = {'b':10, 'c': 11}
>>> s = sorted(set(x) | set(y))
>>> a = [x.get(k, 0) for k in s]
>>> b = [y.get(k, 0) for k in s]
>>> s
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> a
[1, 2, 0]
>>> b
[0, 10, 11]
```

---

Or, as simple code:

```
s = sorted(set(x) | set(y))
a = [x.get(k, 0) for k in s]
b = [y.get(k, 0) for k in s]
```

---

You could use also the `.keys()` method to get the unified list of keys (`x.keys() == set(x)`) as @wim noted:

```
s = sorted(x.keys() | y.keys())
```

Comment: The only part I'm concerned with here is if OP expects it to be with respect to ordering of a, b, c. But ultimately that's the approach I would have gone with too.

Comment: You could use `x.viewkeys() | y.viewkeys()` (or just `.keys()` on python3)

Comment: I was surprised to see `x.keys() | y.keys()`.  It doesn't work with Python2.  `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'list' and 'list'`.  It's interesting Python3 supports such operation

Comment: You don't need to call keys or viewkeys twice. `sorted(x.keys() | y)` will work fine.

Comment: Following up my own comment. On Python3 `dict.keys()` returns `dict_keys` object that has nice operators and methods for set operations.  Big departure from Python2.